# Appropriate usage of == and === in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

I'm new to Java Script 
What is the exact difference between (`==` Vs `===`, `!=` Vs `!==`, etc) in JavaScript?
Have read some articles and wanted to be more clear on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O24XMM1PTqQ

Comment: if a function returns multiple values that are equivalent to false like 0, '0' or false (for example 0 means no result and false and error) and you want them to be treated the same then you can use == but if you want them to be treated differently then you have to use ===.

Answer (score 3):

The `==` operator means equality after type conversion

```
1 == '1';  // true
1 == 1;    // true
```

The `===` operator means equality without any conversion

```
1 === '1'; // false
1 === 1;   // true
```

Comment: Ah so that's why `",,," == new Array(4);` returns `true`... :/

Comment: != and !== do the same thing but consider inequality of values converted and of types.